# What regex can I use to "clean" a sentence from its first characters like 1), or #1, or

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying in Python to "clean up" a string and remove some characters that were added like :

```
"1. bla bla" => i want "bla bla"
"#. bla bla" => same
"3) bla bla" => same
"I. bla bla" => same
```

I tried to use (\W)(\w.*) but doesn't work.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
^.[.)]\s+(.*)
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/NexPhd/1)

---

```py
import re

text = """\
1. bla bla
#. bla bla
3) bla bla
I. bla bla"""

pat = re.compile(r"^.[.)]\s+(.*)", flags=re.M)

for cleaned in pat.findall(text):
    print(cleaned)
```

Prints:

```
bla bla
bla bla
bla bla
bla bla
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xyqLhK/1)

```
(\")[^ ]* ([^\"]*\")
```